# How do I keep my wrapper remain centered when zooming in and out?

Tags: html, css

The problem is my layout does not break on zoom out or in, it just wraps to the left, so at the smallest zoom you would see my layout in the leftmost part of the browser screen.
While I want my layout to decrease in size but not float left. I want it to remain centered perfectly all the time every single zoom.

How do I do that?

```html
<body class="body">
    <div class="wrapper">/</div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

```css
 .body {
     position: absolue;
     top: 0%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 1366px;
     height: 768px;
     background: white;
 }
 .wrapper {
     position: absolute;
     left: 20%;
     right: 20%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     min-height: 100%;
     background: black;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, can you please add the relevant code from your question here.  Questions posted here should ideally be [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: can u give online source ?

Comment: Why would the `body` element need a class called `body`? For the CSS, you can just use the element selector by omitting the period.  Also, jQuery doesn't seem relevant to this question, so you can safely omit the script tag.  It would be great if you can add a fiddle and spend a little bit of time formatting your code to help other people more easily read it and help you.

Comment: Also it's pretty rare to have a body with an absolute position

Comment: Just so you know absolute is spelt incorrectly in the body class `position: absolue;`

Answer (score 0):

On your body tag, put `text-align: center;` this should keep everything centered even when zooming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what isn't working about your code.

Here's an example of the code you provided in jsFiddle which appears to be centering fine at any zoom level.

### [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/7p77E/)

[image: screenshot]

Traditionally the trick to centering a div is `margin: 0 auto;`

But you're doing that, so I think you're okay.

Is there any other formatting you have that is interfering? Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this:

```
<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <!-- all websites HTML here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

---

```
 body {
     text-align: center;
 }

#page-wrap {
  text-align: left;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```